# Need to use my home IP form remote server

Tags: proxy, raspberry-pi, squid

I need to outgoing with my home IP from my remote VPS
So I buy a raspberry pi 3 with raspian and place it at home.
I have install Squid and I setup with this sample rules:

```
acl me src MY_VPS_IP/32
visible_hostname myProxy
http_access allow me
dns_nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid
cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log
http_port 5432 intercept
```

I open port 5432 in my router foreword to my raspberry.

If I try to setup proxy in my firefox from my vps and I navigate to http site proxy server response with access deny in my access log there is

```
TCP_DENIED/403 4091 GET http://www.mio-ip.it/ - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

so... I need to configure same iptables on my raspberry? This is the right way to do this ?? I don't want any cache only IP redirect.
There is method to work with https and http as a transparent proxy? (not configure cert on my vps firefox)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search i found a right configuration... 
only squid no iptables

```
acl localnet src 192.168.178.0/24
acl my_allowed_ip src n.n.n.n/32 # INSERT HERE YOUR IP ALLOWED TO USED PROXY
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80        # http
acl Safe_ports port 21        # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443        # https
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow my_allowed_ip 
http_port PORT  #INSERT HERE YOUR PROXY PORT
http_port PORT transparent #INSERT HERE YOUR PROXY PORT
```